# What is the most efficient way to solve a system of equations where the syms are angles for cos / sin?

Tags: matlab

I have some syms:

```
syms t3a t4a t5a t6a
```

And am using the solve function to grab values for these syms.

```
v1 = (solve(r1+r4*cos(t4a)+r3*cos(t3a)-r2*cos(t2) == 0, r4*sin(t4a)+r3*sin(t3a)-r2*sin(t2) == 0, [t3a, t4a]));
```

However, I am running a very large number of simulations, each simulation having multiple calls of the solve function in this style.

Obviously this is extremely slow.  I am trying to speed it up.  I have looked at using vpasolve, which takes about 50% the runtime of solve.  I have also been looking at fsolve, which I would prefer not to use as I need to restructure my code for it, but will do so if needed.

I can't solve by hand and use an algebraic expression in place of the solve call because the syms are contained inside nonlinear functions (cos and sin).

Is there any efficient way to do this?  Or is vpasolve / fsolve the best I'm going to get?  I was thinking about matrices but don't know how to get around the problem of cos and sin containing the syms.

Comment: symbolic is slow. consider numeric method.

Comment: That's vpasolve right?  That's what I'm using right now, but as I mentioned in the op it's not amazingly fast so I'm looking to see if there are alternatives.  Or is vpasolve not considered a numerical method?

Comment: No, `vpasolve` uses variable precision arithmetic which is not much faster than symbolic math. Try `fsolve`. You can also use `matlabFunction` to convert a symbolic expression to a numeric function (with some initial overhead of course).

Comment: Take a look at Kiusalaas's book. You don't have to implement a solver tho, but some details need considering. It might help to clarify the procedure. You can implement the target equations as functions that take numbers, not symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I implemented fsolve and it's alot faster.